# Google Checkout - no notifications other than 'new-order-notification' coming

Tags: php, google-checkout

I've just set up Google Checkout **PHP Sample code** (1.3.1) with no changes except my merchant_id and key of course. I'm testing it in **sandbox**.

Purchasing demo in works fine but there is **problem with response handling**.

**The only notifications I'm getting are 'new-order-notification'**. No matter what I do with the orders - manual charging, auto charge (set in merchant settings), or just waiting - I only get 'new-order-notification' several times for each order.

googlemessage.log confirms this as there are only this type of notifications logged.

Is this a problem with sandbox or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I found the problem and solution. The acknowledgement calls in the sample code are missing serial key argument.